# カン - What does it mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, translation, words

I'm playing through a game and came across the below line.  It is read by an old man in a fantasy setting - think knights.

```
ワシのカンは あたったようじゃな。
```

From my understanding, `ワシ` means "I" but mainly used by old men.  `の` would indicate possession, `カン` I'm stumped on, which is throwing off my ability to understand the rest of the sentence.  The end of the sentence shows `じゃな`, I believe `じゃ` could be something old people/men do but didn't know what the `な` would indicate after that with my limited understanding.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT 1:
The old man (who speaks the line above) thinks you might be the hero the world needs. A random monster appears, surprising the 'hero' and old man. The old man quips that the hero show his strength, prompting you to fight the monster. Once defeated, he says the above line.

Comment: What's the context? i.e. surround in-game text

Comment: Sorry, I thought I did by using the code brackets.  カン in this sentence: ワシのカンは あたったようじゃな。

Comment: Yes, I can see that. I meant the lines before and after, if any.

Comment: The old man (who speaks the line above) thinks you might be the hero the world needs.  A random monster appears, surprising the 'hero' and old man.  The old man quips that the hero show his strength, prompting you to fight the monster.  Once defeated, he says the above line.

Comment: It's often recommended to wait a bit before accepting an answer, to give the community some time to see the question, as well as to avoid accepting incorrect answers.

Comment: @Leebo I'll leave a bit more time next question I have.  The answer fit what I loosely believed to be correct before the accepted answer was posted.  I'll be sure to get more than a second opinion on my thoughts in the future.
Discussion is important to overall quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write it in less-anime old man 役割語：

<strike>私の感があたったのだな</strike>

NOTE: This was a mistake. Should be

私の勘があたったのだな

To elaborate, 勘 means intuation, hunch or sense.

e.g. 勘がいい

I guess I got confused by 予感 (excuses, excuses)

Comment: 勘違いしてしまいました、so to speak

Comment: This is correct.